# Spring context:component-scan not working with annotated beans

Tags: spring, hibernate, maven

I'm trying to run a simple Spring + Hibernate tutorial => [Maven Spring Hibernate annotation example](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/maven-spring-hibernate-annotation-mysql-example/)

My beans definition file BeanLocations.xml is like this :

```
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd">

        <!-- Database Configuration -->
        <import resource="../database/Datasource.xml"/>
        <import resource="../database/Hibernate.xml" />

        <context:component-scan base-package="com.sample.springhibernate"/>

</beans>
```

My main method:

```
public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        ApplicationContext appContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath*:BeanLocations.xml");
        StockBo stockBo = (StockBo)appContext.getBean("stockBo");
    }
```

I have a defined service with an interface:

```
public interface StockBo {

        public void save(Stock stock);
        public void update(Stock stock);
        public void delete(Stock stock);
        public Stock findByStockCode(String stockCode);
}
```

And his implementation:

```
 @Service("stockBo")
public class StockBoImpl implements StockBo {

    @Autowired
    StockDao stockDao;

    public void setStockDao(StockDao stockDao){
        this.stockDao = stockDao;
    }

    @Override
    public void save(Stock stock) {
        stockDao.save(stock);
    }
........
```

There is any problem with this because spring throws a Exception when StockBo)appContext.getBean("stockBo") :

```
30-oct-2014 15:31:49 org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@64dc11: display name [org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@64dc11]; startup date [Thu Oct 30 15:31:49 CET 2014]; root of context hierarchy
30-oct-2014 15:31:49 org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext obtainFreshBeanFactory
INFO: Bean factory for application context [org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@64dc11]: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@a3d4cf
30-oct-2014 15:31:49 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@a3d4cf: defining beans []; root of factory hierarchy
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'stockBo' is defined
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:387)
```

Spring not foud my annotated service StockBoo (with @Service("stockBo") )....

What is the problem? How can I ensure that Spring recognize my service with component scan?

FYI: StockBo is in com.sample.springhibernate.bo and StockBoImpl in com.sample.springhibernate.bo.impl

Comment: Where is your `BeanLocations.xml` file located?

Comment: Looks like spring did not find `BeanLocations.xml`. You could try to directly declare a bean there to confirm.

Answer (score 0):

If you turn your log level to DEBUG, you'll more than likely find a line like

```
DEBUG o.s.b.f.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loaded 0 bean definitions from location pattern [classpath*:BeanLocations.xml]
```

That is, your `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` did not find any resources that match `classpath*:BeanLocations.xml` and therefore didn't load any context.

You'll need to provide a resource location `String` value that properly identifies and locates the context configuration file.